# jquery isotope overlapping elements even after reloading or relayoutting

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a function, say functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...) which do an ajax call and write/append data to html.

When I do following, everything works fine;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
    :
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
});

function functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...){
    :
    $('#container').append(ajaxresponseElement);      
}

function applyIsotop(){
    isotopIntialized = true;
    $('#Feeds').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $('#Feeds').isotope({
          sortBy : 'random',
          layoutMode: 'masonry',
          itemSelector : '.Feed'
        });
    });
}

$(window).load(function(){
    applyIsotop();
});
```

But doing so many ajax requests makes page loading slow. Since jQuery isotope masonry gets applied on $(window).load(); ie after load, so delay in applying masorny view is clearly visible on screen.

To overcome this problem, I decided to partition ajax function calls in 2 parts as follows;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
});

function loadRest(){
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
    :
    functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...);
}

$(window).load(function(){
    applyIsotop();
    loadRest();
});

function functionForAjaxRequestAndDisplayData(...){
    :
    if(isotopIntialized == false){
                $('#container').append(ajaxresponseElement);
          }else{
              $('#container').append(ajaxresponseElement).isotope( 'insert',$(ajaxresponseElement),function(){
                    $('#container').isotope( 'reLayout')
              })
          }
}
```

But this solution caused overlapping of elements in container. If I use 'reLayout' after adding or inserting items, all elements in all columns get overlapped. If I use 'reloadItems' after adding or inserting items, some elements in first columns get overlapped. However when I use isotope filter, all items re-aligned properly.

I tried to call isotope filter as follows;

```
$(window).load(function(){
    applyIsotop();
    loadRest();
    wait(1000);
    $('#container').isotope({ filter: '*' });
});
```

But it dint work too because it gets executed before all ajax calls completed.

Comment: When I defined `filter : '*'` isotope properties then I met to less overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to get rid from overlapping issue:

```
$container.append(divs).isotope('appended', divs, function () {
    $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

Comment: 7 years ago and still useful for loading external resources such as shopify's but-buttons.